# can't find the way to set the mobile number in android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, virtualbox

I can't find the way to set the mobile number in android emulator. I've installed android 4.3 on virtual box successfully. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an option of receiving calls and SMS on your android emulator. But you cannot set a phone number for your device.

To get a call / SMS to your emulator, in your Eclipse IDE, Select the DDMS tab, under which you will find an option Network and using it you can make calls and send sms to your emulator.